# Getting pointers to the real and imaginary parts of a complex vector in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, g++

Using the standard C++ complex number and vector libraries, I define a vector of complex numbers. Now, I would like to get pointers (of the type `double *`) to the vectors that contain the real and imaginary parts of this complex vector. The following solution works, but is inelegant and wasteful as the memory usage is doubled;

```
using namespace std;
typedef complex<double> cmp;
.
.
int i,m=10;
vector<cmp> C(m);
//Do something to populate the vector C
vector<double> R(m), I(m);
for(i=0; i<m; i++){
 R[i] = C[i].real();
 I[i] = C[i].imag();
}
double * r = &R[0];
double * i = &I[0];
```

Comment: Why do you want pointers?

Comment: You cannot avoid doubling the memory usage if you must have an array of doubles, because real and imaginary parts are not next to each other in the memory.

Comment: There is no safe way to do that. The double primitives are encapsulated inside the `complex<double>` objects. You are trying to solve the higher-level problem at the wrong scope.

Comment: @Jefffrey I need the pointers to pass to a 3rd party code that I have no control over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (C++03) standard does not define how the internals of a `std::complex<double>` look, but usually it consists of 2 doubles, with the real part coming before the imaginary part. Therefore, given an array (or `std::vector`) of `std::complex<double>`, you cannot get a pointer to an array of all real parts, and another pointer to an array of all imaginary parts: Real and imaginary parts are interleaved. If you really need to split them up, you cannot do it without copying all elements (as you already do).

But why do you want to split them up in the first place? To pass them on to some routines of some library? Maybe that library supports the interleaved format, too? In that case you could do a `reinterpret_cast<double*>(&C[0])`. Note, that this is non-standard, but it seems to work in most cases. For more information, see the [documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html#Complex-numbers) of the widely used fftw-library, where this approach is recommended.

If performance is a concern, you should split up the real and imaginary parts right from the beginning, without constructing a `std::complex<double>` vector first.

Comment: thanks for the answer and for alerting me to the same issue in the fftw-library. As you can imagine, I need to do this splitting because certain third party libraries (read: Matlab) want their complex data in separate real and imaginary containers.

Comment: @UdX I think you misread my answer. The fftw-library expects the **interleaved** format. And because std::complex<double> is binary-compatible (in C++11) to double[2] (which is expected by fftw), you can do the cast. When Matlab expects the split format, you must either treat them separately from the very beginning, or do an additional copy-operation (as in your first post).

Comment: Interesting. Help me understand this better: say I have a vector of complex numbers, whose data is stored in memory locations starting with 1,3,5,.. (assuming 1 double is stored/location). Now, if I had a vector of doubles instead, the memory locations would be like 1,2,3,... So, what exactly is the reinterpret cast doing in the case of @Vlad's answer? It would seem that `r` points to 1,3,5,.. and `i` points to 2,4,6,.. but since these are of type `double *`, iterating over them should be accomplished in steps of 1, not 2. Yet, in @Vlad's answer, iterating over `r` and `i` seems to work. :-?

Comment: No, taking `r` and `i` from Vlad's answer, you have the following: `r[0]` gives the real-part of the first number, `r[1]` gives the **imaginary** part of the first number, `r[2]` gives the real part of the second number, `r[3]` gives the imaginary part of the third number. Etc. For `i`: `i[0]` gives the imaginary part of the first number, `i[1]` gives the real part of the second number, `i[2]` gives the imaginary part of the second number. Etc. Therefore, `i` is offset by 1 element compared to `r`. Vlad didn't really answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @Gugi, I understand now. My misunderstanding arose from not carefully examining Vlad's method as applied to a vector of size > 1. I've updated the correct answer as your's now.

Answer (score 4):

According to the C++ Standard

```
If z is an lvalue expression of type cv std::complex<T> then:
— the expression reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z) shall be well-formed,
— reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[0] shall designate the real part of z, and
— reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[1] shall designate the imaginary part of z.
Moreover, if a is an expression of type cv std::complex<T>* and the expression a[i] is well-defined
for an integer expression i, then:
— reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i] shall designate the real part of a[i], and
— reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i + 1] shall designate the imaginary part of a[i].
```

So you can write simply

```
using namespace std;
typedef complex<double> cmp;
.
.
int i,m=10;
vector<cmp> C(m);
//Do something to populate the vector C

double * r = &reinterpret_cast<double(&)[2]>( C[0] )[0];
double * i = &reinterpret_cast<double(&)[2]>( C[0] )[1];
```

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> v( 1, { 1.1, 2.2 } );

    double * r = &reinterpret_cast<double(&)[2]>( v[0] )[0];
    double * i = &reinterpret_cast<double(&)[2]>( v[0] )[1];

    std::cout << *r << '\t' << *i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1.1 2.2
```

Comment: Great, thanks @Vlad for the helpful answer and sample code :).

Comment: This answer is incorrect -- at least for vectors with more than one element.

The memory structure of a `vector<complex>` object is usually `[RIRIRIRIRI...]`, meaning you cannot get a pointer to the real or imaginary parts.

I say usually, because officially, this is up to the implementation of the compiler. In practice though, the memory is usually contiguous.